# Invalid point cloud from Kinect by using openni_camera

Tags: kinect, openni-launch, openni-camera, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu from Natty to Oneiric. Since we were developing a project under ros-electric, I thus upgraded the original ros-electric for Natty to ros-electric for Oneiric too. Unfortunately, now by using "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch", the point cloud data from Kinect all become "NaN" and no point cloud can be displayed in rviz, although rgb image display is fine. If I use "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch", normal point cloud can be displayed in rviz. Since we have to use openni_camera instead of openni_launch, I am wondering why openni_camera does not produce the right point cloud.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59021/invalid-point-cloud-from-kinect-by-using-openni_camera/) by [Ching](https://answers.ros.org/users/4509/ching/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its probabliy a bug on openNi by ros. If you search here you find multiple people with the same problem.
I recomend to put a issue ticket on the github for openni, like this one (or add to this) : https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/issues/13

---

Originally posted by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) with karma: 200 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0